# react-bootstrap-table filter shows bad and headers are not aligned to data

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, react-bootstrap-table

im building a web app using a node js server with babel and react js.

in some pages im using the react-bootstrap-table tag in order to create a table (as shown below) that includes built-in filters of data, and i have 2 main problems:
1. the headers are misaligned with the data colums - bootstrap table tag transpiles into 2 html table tags which is what i think causes the problem in the first place. i've read some posts about the issue and it was supposed to be fixed in version 2.0.0 and im using version 2.9.0

2. im using the built in filters for some of the columns, which generates 2 input scrollers that are supposed to appear one next to each other in the column header but instead shows one under the other. again i've tried to look around but didnt find something useful.

im adding the source-code of the html rendered and a screenshot showing the table (im sorry in advance but the text in the image is mostly hebrew but it doesnt matter much to get the idea)

```
renderTable: function () {
    return (
        <div >
            <button className="w3-btn w3-theme-d5 w3-margin-top w3-round-xxlarge" onClick={this.onClickAddButton}> + </button>
            <BootstrapTable data={this.state.users} options={options} bordered={false} hover striped search searchPlaceholder={constantStrings.search_string}>
                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataField = 'personal.id'
                    dataAlign = 'right'
                    dataSort = {true}
                    filter = { {type: 'TextFilter', placeholder:constantStrings.enterID_string} }
                    isKey = {true}>
                    {constantStrings.userID_string}
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataField = 'personal.firstName'
                    dataAlign = 'right'
                    dataSort = {true}
                    filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', placeholder:constantStrings.enterFirstName_string} }>
                    {constantStrings.firstName_string}
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataField = 'personal.lastName'
                    dataAlign = 'right'
                    filter = { { type: 'TextFilter', placeholder:constantStrings.enterLastName_string} }>
                    {constantStrings.lastName_string}
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataField = 'personal.sex'
                    dataAlign = 'right'
                    filterFormatted dataFormat={ helpers.enumFormatter } formatExtraData={ constantStrings.user_gender }
                    filter={ { type: 'SelectFilter', placeholder:constantStrings.selectGender_string, options: constantStrings.user_gender } }>
                {constantStrings.gender_string}
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataField = 'jobDetails.userType'
                    dataAlign = 'right'
                    filterFormatted dataFormat={ helpers.enumFormatter } formatExtraData={ constantStrings.user_role }
                    filter={ { type: 'SelectFilter', placeholder:constantStrings.selectRole_string, options: constantStrings.user_role } }>
                    {constantStrings.role_string}
                </TableHeaderColumn>


                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataField = 'startDate'
                    dataAlign = 'right'
                    dataFormat={ dateFormatter }
                    filter={ { type: 'DateFilter' ,placeholder:constantStrings.selectStartDate_string} }>
                    {constantStrings.startDate_string}
                </TableHeaderColumn>



                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataAlign = 'right'
                    dataField = 'button'
                    dataFormat = {this.editButton}>
                    "Edit"
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataAlign = 'right'
                    dataField = 'button'
                    dataFormat = {this.deleteButton}>
                    "Delete"
                </TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
        </div>
    )
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue as well..

This is css issue (the file doesn't loaded).

If you are using

> react-bootstrap-table Getting Started

from [here](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/start.html)

you should change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://npmcdn.com/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css">
```

(in index.html file)

Comment: so apparently i didnt import the js file. when using "script src" i get an exception thrown, and when using "script href" there's no exception. but in either way the app is acting the same as before and the problem isnt fixed

Comment: so you were almost right. the problem was with the css file. we used "src" instead of "href". there's no js file as far as i know